# Segregate the input data based on dictionary values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, data-structures

Need to segregate the input data, if its present/absent in the dict:

**Input File:**

```
1,aaaaaaaa3nawwqfzplgms3u4n7kobqq344sqkn3e75zpsek7kxgaskwsba
2,aaaaaaaa3nawwqfzplgms3u4n7kobqq344sqkn3e75zpsek7kxgaskwsba
3,aaaaaaaangdg77mg3cxnialazk7whbtdidftz3rv2bhqrxcvymaecagxdq
4,aaaaaaaa3nawwqfzplgms3u4n7kobqq344sqkn3e75zpsek7kxgaskwsba
5,aaaaaaaa3nawwqfzplgms3u4n7kobqq344sqkn3e75zpsek7kxgaskwsba
6,aaaaaatbmbxncexycbtsyrnhexniqr7g4vypfuksh5ezmzymuw7k2bw4sa
7,aaaaaatbmbxncexycbtsyrnhexniqr7g4vypfuksh5ezmzymuw7k2bw4sa
```

Script to segregate the data from the above file, based on mapping_hash

```
# Check if the col[2] in the file is part of this dictionary
mapping_hash = {"ad1": "aaaaaaaangdg77mg3cxnialazk7whbtdidftz3rv2bhqrxcvymaecagxdq",
           "ad2":"aaaaaaaa3nawwqfzplgms3u4n7kobqq344sqkn3e75zpsek7kxgaskwsba"}

absnt_dict= {}
Present_dict = {}

# Read the file
with open('so_input') as f:
    for row in f:
        row=row.strip().split(',')
        row_number = row[0]
        hash =row[1]
        print("--------------")
        
        for key, value in mapping_hash.items():
            #check if file value is part of mapping_hash dictionary
            if hash == value:
                print "Yes"
                Present_dict[row_number] = mapping_hash.keys()
            else:
                print "Na"
                absnt_dict[row_number] = hash

print Present_dict
print absnt_dict
```

**Output:**

```
--------------
Yes
Na
--------------
Yes
Na
--------------
Na
Yes
--------------
Yes
Na
--------------
Yes
Na
--------------
Na
Na
--------------
Na
Na

Row part of Hash:
    {'1': ['ad2', 'ad1'], '3': ['ad2', 'ad1'], '2': ['ad2', 'ad1'], '5': ['ad2', 'ad1'], '4': ['ad2', 'ad1']}
Row not part of Hash:    
{'1': 'aaaaaaaa3nawwqfzplgms3u4n7kobqq344sqkn3e75zpsek7kxgaskwsba', '3': 'aaaaaaaangdg77mg3cxnialazk7whbtdidftz3rv2bhqrxcvymaecagxdq', '2': 'aaaaaaaa3nawwqfzplgms3u4n7kobqq344sqkn3e75zpsek7kxgaskwsba', '5': 'aaaaaaaa3nawwqfzplgms3u4n7kobqq344sqkn3e75zpsek7kxgaskwsba', '4': 'aaaaaaaa3nawwqfzplgms3u4n7kobqq344sqkn3e75zpsek7kxgaskwsba', '7': 'aaaaaatbmbxncexycbtsyrnhexniqr7g4vypfuksh5ezmzymuw7k2bw4sa', '6': 'aaaaaatbmbxncexycbtsyrnhexniqr7g4vypfuksh5ezmzymuw7k2bw4sa'}
```

Here, based on number of element in the dict, loop will iterate & create a duplicate entries!

1. I expect 6 & 7 should be part of *absnt_dict* & rest all part of *Present_dict*
2. Output of 1 should be `ad2` not like list two values `'1': ['ad2', 'ad1']`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you continue to check even after you encountered a 'Present'

```
Present_dict[row_number] = "Present"
```

So all the hashes are inserted into `absnt_dict`.

You should use membership check instead

```
# Read the file
with open('so_input') as f:
    for row in f:
        row=row.strip().split(',')
        row_number = row[0]
        hash =row[1]
        print("--------------")

        if hash in mapping_hash.values():
                print "Yes"
                Present_dict[row_number] = "Present"
        else:
                print "Na"
                absnt_dict[row_number] = hash
```

Result:

```
{'1': 'Present', '3': 'Present', '2': 'Present', '5': 'Present', '4': 'Present'}
{'7': 'aaaaaatbmbxncexycbtsyrnhexniqr7g4vypfuksh5ezmzymuw7k2bw4sa', '6': 'aaaaaatbmbxncexycbtsyrnhexniqr7g4vypfuksh5ezmzymuw7k2bw4sa'}
```

Comment: [Updated the question] It solves the segregation part. but, fail in the second part where we need to assign the dict key to the final output.

Comment: You need to a build a reverse lookup dictionary of `mapping_hash`, then use the hash value to retrieve the key from it and add the key to the `Present_dict` dictionary.